# jquery appending value to input field

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add dynamically to one my input field values with jquery. But the passed value won't get appended to the target. My code looks as it follows

```
//on click popup modal with a form
    $(document).on('click', '#form', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();         

        $('<div></div>').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
            title: $(this).attr('title'),
            //autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,            
            draggable: true,
            width:900,
            position: ['top',50], 
            close: function(event, ui) 
            { 
                $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
            } 
        });
//this value should be appended to one of the input field, the value exists on alert but is not getting appended
        $('input#inputPrepend cashback').val( $(this).closest('tr').children('td.cashback').text() );

    });
```

> Notes:

```
//this value is picked up from my Jquery Datatable clicked row
$(this).closest('tr').children('td.cashback').text()
//this input field is getting created inside of modal
$('input#inputPrepend cashback')
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="formRow fluid">    
      <span class="grid12">
      <span class="grid2"><label class="form">Cashback</label></span>
      <span class="grid3">
        <div class="input-prepend">
           <span class="add-on">€</span>
              <input style="width:120px;height:30px; position relative; top:-10px"type="text"  id="inputPrepend cashback" type="text"  readonly="readonly" value="" />
        </div>
    </span>
    </span>            
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
$('input#inputPrepend cashback').val( $(this).closest('tr').children('td.cashback').text() );
```

`$(this)` refers to document, not `$('input#inputPrepend cashback')`

You can use that instead:

```
var $input =  $('input#inputPrepend cashback');
$input.val( $input.closest('tr').children('td.cashback').text() );
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I have been trying out but doesn't seems to work.